# Loop doesn't assign string the correct value

Tags: java, loops

There is a slight part of my program that is not working correctly and I just cannot work out why

```
String KEY = "hello"
for (int h = 0; h < message.length(); h++)
{
    keyWord += KEY.charAt(h);
}
```

Once I run the loop the keyWord string does not hold the letters it should of hello, but if I bypass it and just use KEY in my program it will work fine.

Could someone shed some light as to what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: is message.length() always <= KEY.length?

Comment: Hint: Strings are immutable. But share more code please...

Comment: Please give a short but *complete* program. At the moment there's far too much that we're guessing at.

Comment: keyWord is type string and message.length is so that i can create a string that is the same length as an incoming message so I want to have it repeating i.e if the KEY is hello and the message is goodbye I want keyWord to be hellohe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now see what you are trying to do, you are creating a cipher.

```
public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] args){
           String key = "hello";
           String keyWord = "";
           String message = "asdfghj";
           for (int i = 0; i < message.length();i++)
           {
               keyWord += key.charAt(i %key.length());             
           }
           System.out.println(keyWord);
}
}
```

For anyone who is not sure the `%` or modulo operator returns the remainder of division.  For instance 4 % 5 = 4  as 4 / 5 leaves a remainder of 4 because it goes into it 0 times.  Now 6%5 = 1 as 6/5 = 1 R1 .

Comment: I should probably have explained this a bit better, my code doesn't really reflect what I was trying to do when it gets to the end of the keyword length i want it to go back to the start of the keyword and start again so if a message length was 10 i would want hellohello for the keyword is there a way to change this loop to do that?

Comment: That is exactly what the code above would do.  The modulo operator will ensure you dont go beyond the bound of the key length.

Comment: That is perfect thank you, could you just explain to me what the % before key.length does?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (int h = 0; h < message.length(); h++)
```

to

```
for (int h = 0; h < KEY.length(); h++)
```

You are trying to append KEY to keyword... so you need to check its length and not of some other string.

Comment: This could be the problem, but make sure your type for keyWord is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `keyWord` is a String. The problem is that when you do this:

```
keyWord += KEY.charAt(h);
```

The expression `KEY.charAt(h)` is of type `char`, which is an integer value. When you add an integer to a String using `+` (or `+=`), the compiler generates code to add the string representation of the integer value. It does not append the character itself.